# Multi Step Sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I get a result back from an AR query. I can't order the result in the DB (since the resulting models needs to be checked for further logic)

How can I sort the models by a multi step logic?

Is this the proper way of doing this?

```
Model.some_query.sort do |a,b|
 if a.logic1?
  a <=> b
elsif a.logic2?
  a <=> b
elsif a.logic3?
a <=> b
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that the database is unable to handle the logic you need?

Comment: You can create a temporary table, inserting data from your query and sorting it.

Comment: Since your "how do we compare `a` and `b`?" logic only depends on `a`, are you even sure you have a well defined ordering? I think you need to be clearer about what those three logic functions do and what your `a <=> b` expressions really are.

Comment: Your sample code is using the same sorting in all three conditions. Provide the actual sorting type you want. And a bit more detail on what the "logic" method entail.